# Deleting files that have same section of name

Tags: python, duplicates, operating-system

I am trying to go through my image directories and delete duplicate images. However, I want to recursively go through my directories and delete the second image that has the same date as the file name. When I list the files out I do this:

```
my_current_image_path = r'../Desktop/Images/city1'
for f in sorted(listdir(my_current_image_path)):
    print(f)
```

And i get this output:

```
20190602_051825_Visual.tif
20190604_052001_Visual.tif
20190605_044324_Visual.tif
20190605_052033_Visual.tif
20190607_044351_Visual.tif
20190607_051806_Visual.tif
20190611_051850_Visual.tif
```

The 3rd and the 4th entry have the same DAY (05), and the 5th and 6th have the same DAY (07) (filename reads as : DATE_TIME_Visual.tif). I want to be able to use some kind of loop that looks at the image file, and the next image file and then when it sees the day portion of the file name matches, removes that extra image (probably with os.remove) but I am unsure how to go about that. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What if they have the same day in different years or months?

Comment: Loop over the filenames, and make a set containing the dates. If the date is already in the set, remove the file.

Comment: @Barmar oh man, I do need to keep similar years and months, just the specifiic year/month/day duplicate needs to go since they are only seconds apart

Answer (score 0):

Use a `set` to hold the dates that have been seen. If the date is already in the set, remove the file.

```
dates = set()

for f in sorted(listdir(my_current_image_path)):
    date = f.split('_')[0]
    if date in dates:
        os.remove(os.path.join(my_current_image_path, f))
    else:
        dates.add(date)
```

Comment: I am getting the error 'TypeError: descriptor 'add' for 'set' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object'.  Should the file names not be strings?

Comment: Sorry, that should be `dates.add`

Comment: This worked even with different years!! Thank you so much.

Comment: Of course it does. It uses the entire date as the key, not just the day.